# Whats wrong in this menu when it's opened in explorer/edge?

Tags: html, css, menu

If you open this jsfiddle (link below) in explorer/edge you get som extra padding/margin at the top of the menu.
But not in firefox or chrome.

I want to remove that extra space that appears in explorer/edge but don't know where in the code I have to change. Please, can you help me find whats wrong?

```css
/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  float: none;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
  padding: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008ED4;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  display: inline;
  background: #008ED4;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation-breadcumb {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-lines {
  border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      div,
      span,
      applet,
      object,
      iframe,
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      blockquote,
      pre,
      a,
      abbr,
      acronym,
      address,
      big,
      cite,
      code,
      del,
      dfn,
      em,
      img,
      ins,
      kbd,
      q,
      s,
      samp,
      small,
      strike,
      strong,
      sub,
      sup,
      tt,
      var,
      b,
      u,
      i,
      center,
      dl,
      dt,
      dd,
      ol,
      ul,
      li,
      fieldset,
      form,
      label,
      legend,
      table,
      caption,
      tbody,
      tfoot,
      thead,
      tr,
      th,
      td,
      article,
      aside,
      canvas,
      details,
      embed,
      figure,
      figcaption,
      footer,
      header,
      hgroup,
      menu,
      nav,
      output,
      ruby,
      section,
      summary,
      time,
      mark,
      audio,
      video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation-lines {
        border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
        padding: 0;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation-lines {
        border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
        padding: none;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .header-container {
        border: 0;
      }
      
      .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }
      
      .header-container {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #008ED4;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .header-container {
        border: 0;
      }
      
      .container-fluid {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      body {
        line-height: 1;
      }
      
      body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      }
      
      .t-center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      article,
      aside,
      details,
      figcaption,
      figure,
      footer,
      header,
      hgroup,
      menu,
      nav,
      section {
        display: block;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation {
        float: none;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline;
        padding: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation {
        float: none;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline;
        padding: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
      
      ol,
      ul {
        list-style: none;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #008ed4;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
        transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #008ed4;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
        transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main-container">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header-container">
          <div class="row navigation-lines">
            <div class="col-l-12 t-center">
              <!-- Responsive navigation -->
              <nav class="navigation" id="navigation" role="navigation">
                <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                  <ul class="menu" id="menu-menu-1">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-13 current_page_item menu-item-19" id="menu-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/">START</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/om-maleriet/">OM MÅLERIET</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20" id="menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/vad-vi-gor/">VAD VI GÖR</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17" id="menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/nyheter/">NYHETER</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16" id="menu-item-16"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/kontakta/">KONTAKTA</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- /col-l-12 / t-center -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `display: inline` from `.navigation`. Seems that is conflicting with other css.

Something like below

```css
/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  float: none;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*display: inline;*/
  padding: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008ED4;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  display: inline;
  background: #008ED4;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation-breadcumb {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-lines {
  border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      div,
      span,
      applet,
      object,
      iframe,
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      blockquote,
      pre,
      a,
      abbr,
      acronym,
      address,
      big,
      cite,
      code,
      del,
      dfn,
      em,
      img,
      ins,
      kbd,
      q,
      s,
      samp,
      small,
      strike,
      strong,
      sub,
      sup,
      tt,
      var,
      b,
      u,
      i,
      center,
      dl,
      dt,
      dd,
      ol,
      ul,
      li,
      fieldset,
      form,
      label,
      legend,
      table,
      caption,
      tbody,
      tfoot,
      thead,
      tr,
      th,
      td,
      article,
      aside,
      canvas,
      details,
      embed,
      figure,
      figcaption,
      footer,
      header,
      hgroup,
      menu,
      nav,
      output,
      ruby,
      section,
      summary,
      time,
      mark,
      audio,
      video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation-lines {
        border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
        padding: 0;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation-lines {
        border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
        padding: none;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .header-container {
        border: 0;
      }
      
      .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }
      
      .header-container {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #008ED4;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .header-container {
        border: 0;
      }
      
      .container-fluid {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      body {
        line-height: 1;
      }
      
      body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      }
      
      .t-center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      article,
      aside,
      details,
      figcaption,
      figure,
      footer,
      header,
      hgroup,
      menu,
      nav,
      section {
        display: block;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation {
        float: none;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*display: inline;*/
        padding: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation {
        float: none;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*display: inline;*/
        padding: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
      
      ol,
      ul {
        list-style: none;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #008ed4;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
        transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #008ed4;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
        transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main-container">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header-container">
          <div class="row navigation-lines">
            <div class="col-l-12 t-center">
              <!-- Responsive navigation -->
              <nav class="navigation" id="navigation" role="navigation">
                <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                  <ul class="menu" id="menu-menu-1">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-13 current_page_item menu-item-19" id="menu-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/">START</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/om-maleriet/">OM MÅLERIET</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20" id="menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/vad-vi-gor/">VAD VI GÖR</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17" id="menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/nyheter/">NYHETER</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16" id="menu-item-16"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/kontakta/">KONTAKTA</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- /col-l-12 / t-center -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope this will help you some way (y).

Output in ms-edge 
[image]

Comment: @SvenSune are you not seeing same output as attached in answer? you need to remove `display: inline` from each and every place, i guess there is 3 in embedded css and 1 in external css.

Comment: The original padding around the links dissapear :S - and thats not what I want to.

Comment: It's only the padding on top and bottom that dissapear but it seems that the extra padding also has been removed wich is great if I coud add the padding on top and bottom on the links.

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space:nowrap;` in `.navigation`

```css
/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  float: none;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
  padding: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008ED4;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  display: inline;
  background: #008ED4;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation-breadcumb {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-lines {
  border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      div,
      span,
      applet,
      object,
      iframe,
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p,
      blockquote,
      pre,
      a,
      abbr,
      acronym,
      address,
      big,
      cite,
      code,
      del,
      dfn,
      em,
      img,
      ins,
      kbd,
      q,
      s,
      samp,
      small,
      strike,
      strong,
      sub,
      sup,
      tt,
      var,
      b,
      u,
      i,
      center,
      dl,
      dt,
      dd,
      ol,
      ul,
      li,
      fieldset,
      form,
      label,
      legend,
      table,
      caption,
      tbody,
      tfoot,
      thead,
      tr,
      th,
      td,
      article,
      aside,
      canvas,
      details,
      embed,
      figure,
      figcaption,
      footer,
      header,
      hgroup,
      menu,
      nav,
      output,
      ruby,
      section,
      summary,
      time,
      mark,
      audio,
      video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation-lines {
        border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
        padding: 0;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation-lines {
        border-top: 2px solid #008ED4;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #008ED4;
        padding: none;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .header-container {
        border: 0;
      }
      
      .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }
      
      .header-container {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #008ED4;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .header-container {
        border: 0;
      }
      
      .container-fluid {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      body {
        line-height: 1;
      }
      
      body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      }
      
      .t-center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .col-l-12 {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      [class*='col-l'] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      article,
      aside,
      details,
      figcaption,
      figure,
      footer,
      header,
      hgroup,
      menu,
      nav,
      section {
        display: block;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation {
        float: none;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline;
        padding: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation {
        float: none;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline;
        padding: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
        white-space:nowrap;
      }
      
      ol,
      ul {
        list-style: none;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:768px) */
      
      .navigation ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #008ed4;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
        transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
      }
      /* @media screen and (min-width:996px) */
      
      .navigation ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #008ed4;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
        transition: ease-in 0.4s, ease-out 0.2s;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main-container">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header-container">
          <div class="row navigation-lines">
            <div class="col-l-12 t-center">
              <!-- Responsive navigation -->
              <nav class="navigation" id="navigation" role="navigation">
                <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                  <ul class="menu" id="menu-menu-1">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-13 current_page_item menu-item-19" id="menu-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/">START</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/om-maleriet/">OM MÅLERIET</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20" id="menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/vad-vi-gor/">VAD VI GÖR</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17" id="menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/nyheter/">NYHETER</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16" id="menu-item-16"><a href="http://localhost/kunder/poj/kontakta/">KONTAKTA</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- /col-l-12 / t-center -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```